# Bounded from above integral with exponential

Tags: improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to bound from above the following integral $\int_{\left\{|u| \geq u_n\right\}} u^{4} e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2n}} du$ where $u_n = 2 \sqrt{nlogn}$. Could you please give me any idea how I could bound it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to this site! I just answered your question, but next time, please show us what you have done, and where you are stuck. That will help us helping you in a better way. Don't forget to have fun while you are here! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @mickep! next time I will write down my calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality,
$$
2\int_{u_n}^{+\infty}u^4e^{-u^2/2n}\,du\leq 2\biggl(\int_{u_n}^{+\infty}u^3e^{-u^2/2n}\,du\biggr)^{1/2}\biggl(\int_{u_n}^{+\infty}u^5e^{-u^2/2n}\,du\biggr)^{1/2}
$$
The integrals to the right can be calculated exactly by calculus methods. If I did it correctly, the order of the integral will be $\sqrt{n}(\ln n)^3$, which agrees with the order of your integral for large $n$.

Comment: thank you again @mickep ! you applied Cauchy--Schwarz inequality but I am trying to understand how you split the integrals and the powers inside the integrals why it is of power 3 and power 5?

Comment: Write $u^4=u^{3/2}u^{5/2}$. The splitting is done like this to get integrals that we easily can calculate.